# Infer type of variable not returned from function?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to somehow make Typescript infer the variable type without returning it? Similar to how the type is inferred when doing `if (typeof x === 'object') {}`.

```js
// File A
function isObject(value: unknown): boolean {
  // Here I want to say `value` is type `object`
  return (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null && !Array.isArray(value))
}

// File B
const myVariable: unknown = {} // In reality this is a parsed JSON, just need it to be type `unknown`

if (isObject(myVariable)) {
  console.log(myVariable.foo) // Here I want `myVariable` to be inferred as of type `object` instead of `unknown`
}
```

[image: Object is of type 'unknown'.]

Comment: Instead of setting the return type of `isObject` to boolean, you can set it to `value is object` for example.

Comment: Note that the type `object` does not have a property `foo`, so you'll still get a type error. Probably what you want is something more like `Record<string, unknown>`.

Comment: You can make `isObject` a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

Comment: Or go further and make the function test that the object has a `foo` property of the type you want. The predicate "return type" would be `value is {foo: theTypeYouCheckedFor; }`. [Here's an example](https://tsplay.dev/WJXQZN) looking for an object with a property called `foo` that's a string.